# How to build correct sql schema for user money operations?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm trying to build simple app for users to perform money operations(transfer coins to each other, etc). I've decided to separate account info from the user data, so my schema at this moment
[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4rJu.png)

And right now I have a problem: the user should be able to see his current balance all the time. Also he can view the list of related to him operations (income and expenses), and **each of the items in the list must contain information about the state of users balance(how much coins) after that operation**.

I came up with only two solutions, but each of them looks awful from my perspective:

1. Create fields like 'account_from_balance' and
   'account_to_balance' in the 'operation' table. Here comes other
   problems - such as a possibility of desynchronization between the
   balance in the 'operation' table and the balance in the
   'user_account' table
2. Remake the whole 'operation' table with the fields like:  user_1,
   user_2, amount, type (income/expense), user_1_balance

   The point is when, for example, two users A and B have 80 coins
   each, and the user A decide to send 30 coins to user B, the next two
   rows in 'operation' table will be created:

   ```
   A B 30 expense 50 

   B A 30 income 110
   ```

   But this solution just duplicates all the info except the
   balance info and also has the same problem as the solution number 1.

---

Is there a simplier and nicer way to do what I want? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are describing in your example is a transaction table, it's a common double entry accounting scenario, for any *transaction* between 2 entities, or accounts there is a **debit** entry in one account and a corresponding **credit** in the other, resulting in 2 entries in the transaction table. You should definitely link these two rows together somehow, either with the same timestamp, or through a transaction header or something unique about the physical transaction, so you might have a Header table, perhaps called operation, that records the operation, and the Transaction table holds a link to the operation table. This structure could easily support a single monetary transaction event that took funds from a single account and distributed to many.

> *Theoretically*, you can now sum that transaction table for any given account to find the current balance, and as such you will not need to record the balance anywhere as a specific stored field

It is good that you naturally found your way towards this solution, I don't want to get too technical in this response, as it is a very broad topic.

In theory, as stated above, you may not need to store the 'current' balance, however in practice, unless you have a good RDBMS engine, good indexes and a good command of the necessary syntax, it may prove practical to also have a corresponding field to hold the *accumulated* balance value, rather than re-calculating this value for every query.

If you do try to store the balance, you should ensure that you have control over all inputs to the table, triggers might be useful, application logic is acceptable, but be wary of computed fields, make sure they are compiled such that they are evaluated on write operations, not read operations... assuming there will be many more reads vs writes.

---

**UPDATE:** Regarding `each of the items in the list must contain information about the state of users balance (how much coins) after that operation.`

Depending on your chosen RDBMS, there should be standard mechanisms for calculating running totals on reads so that you do not need to record them. You must weigh the impact on performance, storage costs and maintenance between storing the running total or calculating it, the following is an example designed for SQL Server 2012 (and above) and uses a window function to calculate the running total, keeping the

> Even if you store the running total, you may find window functions useful to back fill or audit the transactions periodically to ensure the balance fields are correct.

```
-- Example Operation Header Table
DECLARE @Operation as Table
(
    Id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    TxDate DateTimeOffset(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT(SysDateTimeOffset()),
    [Description] char(120) NOT NULL
)

-- Example Transaction Table
DECLARE @Transaction as Table
(
    Id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    OperationId bigint NULL,
    TxDate DateTimeOffset(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT(SysDateTimeOffset()),
    [Description] char(120) NOT NULL,
    Account char(1) NOT NULL,
    Amount MONEY NOT NULL
)

-- Insert Starting balances
INSERT INTO @Transaction (Account,[Description],Amount) VALUES ('A','Initial Balance',100.00);
INSERT INTO @Transaction (Account,[Description],Amount) VALUES ('B','Initial Balance',100.00);
INSERT INTO @Transaction (Account,[Description],Amount) VALUES ('C','Initial Balance',0.00);

-- INSERT Some Transactions
DECLARE @opId bigint;
INSERT INTO @Operation ([Description]) VALUES ('A pays B and C $25.60 for services rendered')
SELECT @opId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO @Transaction (OperationId, Account,[Description],Amount) VALUES (@opId,'A','A pays B and C $25.60 for services rendered',-51.20);
INSERT INTO @Transaction (OperationId, Account,[Description],Amount) VALUES (@opId,'B','A pays B and C $25.60 for services rendered',25.60);
INSERT INTO @Transaction (OperationId, Account,[Description],Amount) VALUES (@opId,'C','A pays B and C $25.60 for services rendered',25.60);

INSERT INTO @Transaction (Account,[Description],Amount) VALUES ('C','Buy lunch',-8.20);
INSERT INTO @Transaction (Account,[Description],Amount) VALUES ('A','Buy petrol',40.00);
INSERT INTO @Transaction (Account,[Description],Amount) VALUES ('A','Sell Goods',120.00);

INSERT INTO @Operation ([Description]) VALUES ('B lends $50 to C')
SELECT @opId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO @Transaction (OperationId, Account,[Description],Amount) VALUES (@opId,'B','B lends $50 to C',-50);
INSERT INTO @Transaction (OperationId, Account,[Description],Amount) VALUES (@opId,'C','B lends $50 to C',50);

-- Example of checking current balance on the spot
DECLARE @balance MONEY = (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM @Transaction WHERE Account = 'C')
SELECT @balance as 'C Account Balance'
if(@balance > 80)
    INSERT INTO @Transaction (Account,[Description],Amount) VALUES ('C','Go out for dinner',-80);
else
    INSERT INTO @Transaction (Account,[Description],Amount) VALUES ('C','Get a pizza',-10);


SELECT * from @Operation
SELECT * from @Transaction

-- Current Balance of all accounts
SELECT Account, Balance = SUM(Amount)
FROM @Transaction
GROUP BY Account

-- Running Balance with Transactions
SELECT t.*, Balance = SUM(Amount) OVER(Partition By Account ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
FROM @Transaction t
ORDER BY Id

-- Running Balance, just for Account=C
SELECT t.*, Balance = SUM(Amount) OVER(Partition By Account ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
FROM @Transaction t
WHERE Account = 'C'
ORDER BY Id
```

> The above script is safe to run, it uses table variables so nothing should be left hanging around :)

Ultimately, this results in the following output for all transactions (I have omitted the TxDate column, in this example the dates are all the same and so not useful):

```
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| Id | OperationId | Description                                 | Account | Amount | Balance |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 1  | NULL        | Initial Balance                             | A       | 100.00 | 100.00  |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 2  | NULL        | Initial Balance                             | B       | 100.00 | 100.00  |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 3  | NULL        | Initial Balance                             | C       | 0.00   | 0.00    |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 4  | 1           | A pays B and C $25.60 for services rendered | A       | -51.20 | 48.80   |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 5  | 1           | A pays B and C $25.60 for services rendered | B       | 25.60  | 125.60  |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 6  | 1           | A pays B and C $25.60 for services rendered | C       | 25.60  | 25.60   |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 7  | NULL        | Buy lunch                                   | C       | -8.20  | 17.40   |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 8  | NULL        | Buy petrol                                  | A       | 40.00  | 88.80   |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 9  | NULL        | Sell Goods                                  | A       | 120.00 | 208.80  |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 10 | 2           | B lends $50 to C                            | B       | -50.00 | 75.60   |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 11 | 2           | B lends $50 to C                            | C       | 50.00  | 67.40   |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 12 | NULL        | Get a pizza                                 | C       | -10.00 | 57.40   |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Where possible, if you find a need to store the balance, use database features such as materialized views or indexed views where the *database engine* takes care of updating and maintaining the value automatically.

Comment: Yes but if you use these features, I can't stress enough that you should make sure they evaluate on writes, not for every read, otherwise you may see unexpected performance degradation over time